# st_aggrid nested grids don't display changed data after DF is altered

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, ag-grid, streamlit

Using ...
streamlit==1.9.0
streamlit-aggrid==0.2.3.post2
Python 3

I'm attempting to use nested AgGrid Grids as described [here](https://github.com/PablocFonseca/streamlit-aggrid/blob/main/examples/nested_grids.py) 

The end goal is to show a list of instruments and, (only) when checked, the subgrid below the instrument updates with data about the instrument.

***The problem is; the updated Grid (updated after selecting a checkbox, which alters the underlying DataFrame) does not actually show the new DF data (it still shows the old data.)***

DETAILS:

- When I first load the page, it creates a DataFrame `st.session_state["instruments_and_injections_df"]` correctly using `build_initial_instruments_df()`
- The Grid appears correctly, with the nested data, and checkboxes next to each line in both the outer grid, and the nested grid.
  [image: Correct grid]
  [image: Correct nested grid]
- Selecting a checkbox ***does trigger*** `_get_injection(instrument_name)` and `_update_instruments_and_injections_df(...)`
- These **functions have been validated as working** (it does query the database and update the DF with the new data.) If I dump the updated DF `st.session_state["instruments_and_injections_df"]` we can see the JSON data has been correctly added to the `instrumentData` column on the correct row.
  [image: Data is not updated in the grid]
- **After selecting a checkbox, however, the data in the main grid does not change** (still shows the `"instrumentData": {"sample_name":"test"}`, not the new data)
- Selecting a second checkbox, also queries the database, and updates the Df - but then the grid is completely goofy.
- **I have tried changing the `update_mode` in `AgGrid()` call to *"MANUAL", "VALUE_CHANGED", "SELECTION_CHANGED", and "MODEL_CHANGED"*. The behavior does not change.**

  ```
    def build_initial_instruments_df():
        """ This works to build initial grid. Grid behaves correctly at this point"""
        st.session_state["raw_json"] = json.dumps([
                                                    { "instrument_name":"Inst1", "instrumentData": {"sample_name":"test"}, 
                                                    { "instrument_name":"Inst2", "instrumentData": {"sample_name":"test"}
                                                    ])
        st.session_state["instruments_and_injections_df"] = pd.read_json(st.session_state["raw_json"])
        st.session_state["instruments_and_injections_df"]["instrumentData"] = st.session_state["instruments_and_injections_df"]["instrumentData"].apply(lambda x: pd.json_normalize(x))

    def _update_instruments_and_injections_df(selected = [], always_update = False):
    """ This works to query database, and update the field "instrumentData" with JSON. 
        Verified by dumping updated st.session_state["instruments_and_injections_df"] to screen which shows the updated JSON cell"""
        _instruments = st.session_state["instruments_and_injections_df"]["instrument_name"].to_list()
        for _instrument in _instruments:
            if _instrument in selected:
                _injection_json = _get_injection(_instrument)
                _instrument_index = st.session_state["instruments_and_injections_df"].index[st.session_state["instruments_and_injections_df"]['instrument_name']==_instrument].tolist()[0]
                st.session_state["instruments_and_injections_df"].at[_instrument_index, "instrumentData"] = _injection_json

    def _get_injection(instrument_name):
        """ This works to obtain the data from the DB and convert it to JSON"""
        with st.spinner("Displaying results..."):
            _sql = "SELECT  sample_name, sample_orderno, sample_amount FROM injections WHERE instrument_name = '{}';".format(instrument_name)

            injection_df = pd.read_sql(_sql, st.session_state["conn"])
            injection_df_json = injection_df.to_json(orient = "records")
            injection_df_json = json.loads(injection_df_json)
            return injection_df_json

    #===============================================================================
    # MAIN
    #===============================================================================
        try:
            st.session_state["instruments_and_injections_df"] # Will error if has never been loaded
        except (KeyError, NameError):
            build_initial_instruments_df()

        gridOptions = {
            # enable Master / Detail
            "masterDetail": True,
            "rowSelection": "multiple",
            "pagination": st.session_state["enable_pagination"],
            "paginationAutoPageSize": st.session_state["paginationAutoSize"],
            "groupSelectsChildren":st.session_state["groupSelectsChildren"], 
            "groupSelectsFiltered":st.session_state["groupSelectsFiltered"],

            # the first Column is configured to use agGroupCellRenderer
            "columnDefs": [
                {
                    "field": "instrument_name",
                    "cellRenderer": "agGroupCellRenderer",
                    "checkboxSelection": True,
                },
            ],
            "defaultColDef": {
                # "flex": 1,
            },
            # provide Detail Cell Renderer Params
            "detailCellRendererParams": {
                # provide the Grid Options to use on the Detail Grid
                "detailGridOptions": {
                    "rowSelection": "multiple",
                    "suppressRowClickSelection": True,
                    "enableRangeSelection": True,
                    "pagination": st.session_state["enable_pagination"],
                    "paginationAutoPageSize": st.session_state["paginationAutoSize"],
                    "groupSelectsChildren":st.session_state["groupSelectsChildren"], 
                    "groupSelectsFiltered":st.session_state["groupSelectsFiltered"],
                    "columnDefs": [
                                {"field": "sample_name", "checkboxSelection": True},
                    ],
                    "defaultColDef": {
                        "sortable": True,
                        # "flex": 1, # This sets the columns to fit to the window (bad)
                    },
                },
                "getDetailRowData": JsCode(
                    """function (params) {
                        console.log(params);
                        params.successCallback(JSON.parse(params.data.instrumentData));
            }"""
               ).js_code,
            },
        }


        st.session_state["instruments_grid_response"] = AgGrid(
            st.session_state["instruments_and_injections_df"],
            gridOptions=gridOptions,
            height=st.session_state["grid_height"],    
            allow_unsafe_jscode=True,
            enable_enterprise_modules=True,
            # update_mode=GridUpdateMode.SELECTION_CHANGED,
            data_return_mode=st.session_state["return_mode_value"], 
            update_mode=st.session_state["update_mode_value"],    
        )

    #===============================================================================
    # Discover any data selected from grid
    #===============================================================================
        if st.session_state["instruments_grid_response"]['selected_rows'] != []:
            _selected_instruments = pd.DataFrame(st.session_state["instruments_grid_response"]['selected_rows'])["instrument_name"].to_list()
            _update_instruments_and_injections_df(selected = _selected_instruments)
        else: 
            st.write("No instruments selected")
  ```